# ERROR: TLS configuration is invalid - make sure your DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY and DOCKER_CERT_PATH are set correctly. on windows

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I went through links like https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3021 and https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3937, but still I am facing below error:

```
C:\Users\pc\Downloads\docker-compose-scripts>docker-compose up --d
ERROR: TLS configuration is invalid - make sure your DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY and DOCKER_CERT_PATH are set correctly.
You might need to run `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`
```

Versions of docker

```
C:\Users\pc>docker --version
Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289

C:\Users\pc>docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.29.1, build c34c88b2
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For intellij, it can also be resolved by adding `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`and `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` to your run/debug configuration as environment variables.

The value of each can be empty (depending on your docker setup) so the run/debug configuration shows:
`DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=;DOCKER_CERT_PATH=`

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem with docker-compose under Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with Pycharm 2021.1.1 (Community Edition). The run configuration would not work, but it started fine in the terminal.

The problem was the docker-server
[image]

I recreated it (with the same default settings) and it worked
[image]

It seems to be some kind of configuration issue. I reintalled docker-compose at one point, maybe this has something to do with it. Seeing you are on Windows you will probably have to do something slightly different, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Worked for me. Simply adding a new Docker setting with the same configuration as default.

Comment: Unfortunately, just recreate Docker settings didn't work to me in `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`, `PyCharm 2021.1.2 (Professional)` and `Docker 20.10.7`

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with RubyMine 2021.2.3

In config file `.config/JetBrains/RubyMine2021.2/options/remote-servers.xml`
remove line `<option name="certificatesPath" value="$USER_HOME$/.docker" />`