# Docker Desktop error: TLS configuration is invalid (problem with DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY and DOCKER_CERT_PATH )

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I installed Docker Desktop on my Windows 10 machine (v4.9.1). It worked fine until I deleted *Docker* and *.docker* configuration folders (as much as possible). *(I regret it now.)* Now, I want to start my docker-compose.yml and get this:

```
PS C:\test> docker-compose up -d
ERROR: TLS configuration is invalid - make sure your DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY and DOCKER_CERT_PATH are set correctly.
You might need to run `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`
```

I uninstalled the Docker Desktop and installed it again and I still have the same.
I searched on the internet and found some [possible solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639257/error-tls-configuration-is-invalid-make-sure-your-docker-tls-verify-and-docke), but I want to understand the problem because this is the first time I have used Docker Desktop.

EDIT:

There is a tutorial power shell command line in Docker Desktop after starting it. The docker-compose works there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I removed DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY and DOCKER_CERT_PATH environment variables. These pointed to deleted configuration. Anyway, I don't need this now.
Furthermore, I couldn't see these environment variables in Docker Desktop PowerShell, thus I could work there. It confused me a bit. I don't know why the Docker Desktop environment is different. In the past I had Docker installation on my machine, maybe this also could cause problems.